# Synthesizer humming

Tags: synthesizer

I have a Synthesizer (quite old but working) which makes a humming noise when powered on (not through the audio output).
I wonder if it is a major undertaking to fix this. Is this something that sounds familiar to experts? The synthesizer has no internal moving parts like fans or discs. I'm happy to provide more details, don't know how else to describe it.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a good old-fashioned mains AC power transformer that is vibrating at 50 or 60 cycles per second. Probably not a switching power supply - they tend to whistle and squeak rather than hum.

Comment: Actually it would be at 100 or 120Hz, but that's just nit-picking.

Comment: It may be at 50H/60Hz

Comment: Usually not. http://www.federalpacific.com/literature/drytrans/10transformernoise.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Does it have switching power supply?

If so try pressing on the power inductors with your finger to see if the humming disappears.

The inductor cores can work loose in their housing over time causing a hum.